# SqlConnection from class into SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Hello I have got this code in class which runs SqlConnection:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace tours
{
    class myConnection
    {
        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
                string path = "C:\\Users\\marek\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\tours\\tours\\sql_string.txt";
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));

                string str = "Data Source='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';Initial Catalog ='" + sr.ReadLine() + "' ;User ='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';Password = '" + sr.ReadLine() + "'";

                SqlConnection spojeni = new SqlConnection(str);
                spojeni.Open();
                return spojeni;
        }
    }
}
```

In other forms I got `SqlCommand` or `SqlDataAdapter` and I need to add to them `SqlConnection`, but don't know how can I access them? Would you please suggest me something? for example this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM zajezd",);
SDA.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: You don't "add" a SqlCommand to a SqlConnection. Were you perhaps looking for the `SqlDataAdapter(string, SqlConnection)` constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM zajezd",tours.myConnection.GetConnection())
```

or you already add `using tours;` in top of your file then you can call as `myConnection.GetConnection()`

**Note:**

**make myConnection as public**

```
public class myConnection
```

if `myConnection` is in separate class library you need to add reference to data class library

---

I would change the connection class return only the connection string, like below

```
public class myConnection
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string connection = string.Empty;
        string path = "C:\\Users\\marek\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\tours\\tours\\sql_string.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            connection = "Data Source='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';Initial Catalog ='" + sr.ReadLine() + "' ;User ='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';Password = '" + sr.ReadLine() + "'";

        } 

        return connection;

    }
}
```

When we need to access database,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnection.GetConnectionString()))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM zajezd", con))
{
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
```

In case of you need `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteScalar`

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnection.GetConnectionString()))
using (SqlCommand commad = new SqlCommand("sql statements", con))
{
    con.Open();
    commad.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    //var result = commad.ExecuteScalar();

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much, I tried to do this: ("SELECT * FROM zajezd", myConnection.myConnection()); but it said: tours.myConnection does not contaion definition for 'myConnection' How should I improve it ? thanks again.

Comment: @Marek have you change myConnection as public?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm not sure now where the problém is :/

Comment: Thank oyu so much, Is there way to do something like: connection.Close(); and connection.Open()? I think I need this for Execute

Comment: @Marek for `SqlDataAdapter` you don't need to have open connection, SqlDataAdapter will open the connection when needed, you better get connection string from static class and create connection from what when you need. i'll update the answer. give me few minutes

Comment: Thank you so much, but what to do with SqlCommand and its ExecuteNonQuery() that I use?

Answer (score 0):

your method name is GetConnection() not myConnection